# Jsoup I want select div , not select span or all a

Tags: java, jsoup

```html
<div class="conditions-race">
 Çim: Ağır 4,9 Kum: Normal Hava: 14 C , PARÇALI BULUTLU , NEM %50
  <span style="float: right;">
   <a id="PDFBulten">PDF Programı</a>
   <a id="PDFOzetBulten">Özet PDF Programı</a>
   <a id="CSVBulten">CSV Programı</a>
   <a href="javascript: void(0)">1. AGF Tablosu</a>
   <a href="javascript: void(0)">2. AGF Tablosu</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

I want only this line "Çim: Ağır 4,9 Kum: Normal Hava: 14 C , PARÇALI BULUTLU , NEM %50"

Comment: what you need , give clear idea and where you are facing problem? are you trying to extract `&#199;im: Biraz Yumuşak 3,4 Kum: Normal Hava: AZ BULUTLU 24 &#39;C, NEM %35`

Comment: <div class="conditions-race">
 Çim: Ağır 4,9 Kum: Normal Hava: 14 C , PARÇALI BULUTLU , NEM %50
  <span style="float: right;">
   <a id="PDFBulten">PDF Programı</a>
   <a id="PDFOzetBulten">Özet PDF Programı</a>
   <a id="CSVBulten">CSV Programı</a>
   <a href="javascript: void(0)">1. AGF Tablosu</a>
   <a href="javascript: void(0)">2. AGF Tablosu</a>
  </span>
</div>

I want only this line Çim: Ağır 4,9 Kum: Normal Hava: 14 C , PARÇALI BULUTLU , NEM %50
Ç = &#199; Sry for Turkish characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [Element#ownText](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText--) method.

#### Extract from Javadoc

> *Gets the text owned by this element only; does not get the combined text of all children.
>
>
> For example, given HTML `<p>Hello <b>there</b> now!</p>`, p.ownText() returns "Hello now!", whereas p.text() returns "Hello there now!".
>
>
> Note that the text within the b element is not returned, as it is not a direct child of the p element.*

#### Sample code

```
Document doc = ...

for(Element div : doc.select("div.conditions-race")) {
   System.out.println(div.ownText());
}
```

Comment: Tnks mf i fix it ownText